# Batmanjs internationalization

Tags: internationalization, batman.js

I'm trying to add translation to my batmanjs app but there are no tutorials or documentation available on the subject. Do you guys know where we can find any resource on the subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is a bit old but ... just wrote docs for `Batman.I18N`! http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.i18n.html Hope it helps someone anyways :)